# Is there a way to force a Platform Event Trigger to honor the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig in unit tests?

Tags: unit-test, platform-event

I'm attempting to move an integration away from using Custom SObjects and to using Platform Events out of a concern for storage space (and also so our eventual automation of this integration won't have to delete 500k rows before each run).

I have the Platform Event, a Platform Event Trigger, and a PlatformEventSubscriberConfig (which is still a real hassle to create and edit) to change the running user away from "Automated Process User". I've made myself the running user and the subscriber config has taken effect, as I can see the logs when I publish an appropriate Platform Event from anonymous apex.

When I publish a Platform Event from the unit test meant to stress the Platform Event Trigger, however, Salesforce appears to be ignoring my configuration.

In my case, that's causing a test method to run afoul of a validation rule (PE causes an Account name to be changed, and only certain profiles are allowed to do that. The "Automated Process" profile is currently not in the pass-list).

I can, and have, worked around the issue for this one particular test failure, but it seems wrong to me that Salesforce isn't honoring the configuration I set up. I imagine that this is a side-effect of how Salesforce is currently isolating the Event Bus for tests.

Is there a way to force Salesforce to set a running user for a Platform Event Trigger in a unit test (or force Salesforce to honor the configuration I've already set up)?

Comment: Is this for your unpackaged metadata, a managed package, a second-generation managed package, or an unlocked package? Is this going to be used for deployments, or just for building package versions? Have you considered using a Custom Permission so you can just assign it to the Automated User during testing (which would also be a best practice for validation rules, instead of using profiles to control this)?

Comment: @sfdcfox This is currently unpackaged metadata, but eventually will be part of an unlocked package. The plan is to icnlude the subscriber config in deployments/installs. I have not yet considered custom permissions (I really should, though that'd be a project for another time).

Comment: @DerekF did you get any findings on this, I'm also facing the same issue that tests are not taking the config into consideration?

Comment: @AdityaVijay I have not, mostly because I don't want to spend a month or more trying to work through Salesforce's "support" process.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and logged a ticket - they have it marked up as a bug with a known issue link: 
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000020gA7QAI

Comment: The PlatformEventSubscriberConfig User is still not respected in test methods, but the batchSize is respected.