# Problem with PlatformEventSubscriberConfig user change being ignored

Tags: trigger, salesforcedx, metadata, platform-event

The context here is at normal runtime not in Apex tests as discussed here [Is there a way to force a Platform Event Trigger to honor the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig in unit tests?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/356851/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-platform-event-trigger-to-honor-the-platformeventsubsc).

I'm using this metadata deployed using SFDX to get a `ChangeEvent` Platform Event trigger to run as user `test-xxxxxxxxxxxx@example.com`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlatformEventSubscriberConfig xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <platformEventConsumer>ChangeEvent</platformEventConsumer>
    <batchSize>200</batchSize>
    <masterLabel>ChangeEvent</masterLabel>
    <user>test-xxxxxxxxxxxx@example.com</user>
    <isProtected>false</isProtected>
</PlatformEventSubscriberConfig>
```

and this was working.

Having re-organized the files and having re-pushed (and re-deployed) the user assignment is **no longer working.** This query run from the Developer Console with "Use Tooling API" checked:

```
select Id, DeveloperName, User.Name, PlatformEventConsumer.Name from PlatformEventSubscriberConfig
```

outputs all the expected values.

I'm stuck. Any suggestions for how to further debug this?

Comment: does this happen for all your platform event subscribers (i.e. on objects other than `ChangeEvent`)?

Comment: Hi @cropredy, This the start of a proof of concept so I only have one platform event. Was thinking about replacing the trigger Apex or changing the user as the metadata links to those. But best to include the event too. I'll try that next.

Comment: Failed to switch user with a simple case `TestEvent__e` too. I'll try a new scratch org.

Comment: I'm starting to think that there is a big time delay involved once the Platform Event has been used for any further change to make a difference. Will investigate that further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple test case I observe:

- On first deployment, a Platform Event, its trigger and a PlatformEventSubscriberConfig do apply the specified user
- If the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig is then modified the change does not have any affect (at least for the 10 mins or so I waited): the old user continues to be used
- If you delete Platform Event, its trigger and a PlatformEventSubscriberConfig, and then re-create those with a changed user, the changed user does apply

The example in the [PlatformEventSubscriberConfig](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm) does show the deployment of all three components, though does not state that that is a requirement.

(I have some debug logs 40 minutes apart that suggest a change made just to the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig is applied after that amount of time of inactivity but not certain about that.)

**PS**

Can't get the changed user to stick in one org. This [Run Apex trigger for Salesforce Platform Event as specified user](https://lekkimworld.com/2021/10/28/run-apex-trigger-for-salesforce-platform-event-as-specified-user/) post says:

> The metadata deployed just fine but it didn’t take effect. To fix it I had to delete the trigger from the org and the redeploy the trigger and the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig configuration at the same time.

**PPS**

Nothing I tried worked. I created a support case for one instance of the problem but in the several days it took to set up a call the problem fixed itself.

Happened to me again over the weekend. This time it self-corrected after 3 days. So if you are not in  hurry, wait 3 days.

Comment: i was going to suggest there's a SFDC delay in "taking-up" the change as I vaguely recall seeing this myself. I know I've deployed changes to the PESC's User and it worked without me having to delete the trigger - but how "long" it took to work I don't recall as I did it back in 2020 (?)

Comment: Thanks @cropredy - helpful. Somewhere over the next few days I'll try to reproduce the change the user case at 40 mins. Might also be necessary for the org to not be touching the Platform Event in that time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in my Case:

1. Open Setup > Platform Events
2. Open Event Class with PlatformEventSubscriberConfig
3. At Subscriptions click on Manage
4. Suspend Subscription and activate it again.

Now new config takes effekt

[image]